# css not work after deploy NextJS project to Vercel

Tags: css, next.js, deployment, tailwind-css, vercel

in local:
[run in local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzIzq.png)
when deploy:
[when deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaxT4.png)
tailwind config file:
[tailwind config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2qjQ.png)

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use  of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem. My solution was to move my component and page folders inside the `src` folder and add it to the content in `tailwind.config.js`. It looks like my nextjs project was configured to use the src folder in the deployment. In your case, it could be the experimental `app` folder.